# Initialise mutex globally in C

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I have some code where two 2 threads modify the value of the same variable but with two different functions. So I decided to use a common mutex. That for: I initialised it globally :

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>


#define perror_pthread(ret, msg) \
        do { errno = ret; perror(msg); } while (0)



pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;      /*define a mutex-object */ 
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);  /*initialise this mutex object with default values */
```

I get an error message :

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);  /*initialise this mutex object with default values */
                    ^
```

I don't know if that's a good practice, but I feel like both functions should have the same mutex in order to be informed when there is lock

Comment: The point behind `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is to initialize a mutex object in the same way that `pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);` would initialize it, but doing it as an initializer rather than an executable statement.  You don't need both — either is sufficient.

Comment: when you say do it " doing it as an initializer rather than an executable statement" , could you elaborate a little bit more? I did both because I thought that the first statement initialises the variable mutex, of type pthread_mutex_t  and the second somehow intialises an object mutex... But this is my first experiment with documentation so I am pretty unsure of everything

Comment: in my mind it was something like system calls like read, we declare for example : ```char buf[1200] ``` then we write something like ```read(fd,buf,len(buf);``` but every argument in this system call is pre-declared.

Comment: I mean that `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` is an initialized variable, and not an executable statement.  I also mean that `pthread_mutex_t mutex; … pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);` achieves the same result as initializing the mutex with the initializer, but it involves an executable statement and the call to the function must itself be inside a function — it cannot be written outside of a function.  This is standard terminology.

Comment: aaa so you mean that i can not globally declare a mutex with ```pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);``` because it needs to be inside a function ( or at least a main?) ??

Comment: You shouldn't declare system calls — you should include the relevant header that declares the system calls (`#include <unistd.h>` for `read()`, for example).  And `pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);` is an executable statement, not a declaration (or even a definition). —— And `main()` is just a function except that it is special because "the implementation" arranges to call it as the first step in executing your code when your program is run.  (That applies to 'hosted implementations', the normal sort; the rules are different for 'freestanding implementations'.)

Comment: Using `pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)` never declares anything — it invokes a function on a previously declared variable (and you can only invoke functions inside another function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_init` is a function and C forbids expressions (i.e. function calls) at the file scope.

Either use static initializer or put `pthread_mutex_init(...)` into beginning of `main()`.